# convert array to array of array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting data from a Firebase database and want to be able to pass it into a function to be used in a Google Map. The required/desired format is below. I can get the data from Firebase into an but want to reformat it somehow to put it into the correct format.

I have passed the array itself and then tried to push it into the locations array but that obviously doesn't work.

Here is a console.log(); of the array and the format.
[image: log]

Current Array:

```
var array =  ["Stop1, 37.3329891813207, -122.039420719004", "Stop2, 37.3320091546085, -122.036849794357", "Stop3, 37.3310547072562, -122.034668026436", "Stop4, 37.3301791417375, -122.033242200136", "Stop5, 37.3307185698498, -122.030606204886"]

initMap(array)
```

Desired Format:

```
function initMap(passedArray) {
```

//..Convert array here?..

```
    var locations = [
        ['Stop1', 37.3329891813207, -122.039420719004],
        ['Stop2', 37.3320091546085, -122.036849794357],
        ['Stop3', 37.3310547072562, -122.034668026436],
        ['Stop4', 37.3301791417375, -122.033242200136],
        ['Stop5', 37.3307185698498, -122.030606204886]
    ];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `array.map(x => x.split(',').map( y => isNaN(y) ? y : +y))` -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/o7wj9v59/

Comment: @adeneo, Thank you, this is great. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Split by separator `', '` and parse numbers.

```js
var array =  ["Stop1, 37.3329891813207, -122.039420719004", "Stop2, 37.3320091546085, -122.036849794357", "Stop3, 37.3310547072562, -122.034668026436", "Stop4, 37.3301791417375, -122.033242200136", "Stop5, 37.3307185698498, -122.030606204886"]

const initMap = array => array
      .map(str => str.split(', ').map((x, i) => (i ? parseFloat(x) : x)))

console.log(initMap(array))
```

Comment: This works, but using @adeneo's answer is much simpler for my code. I appreciate your help, you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Eric.18 Well, ok :) But the difference is almost neglectable: the same split and convert to a number the second and the third part.